# Environment Variables with Ava

Tags: express, webpack, environment-variables, ava

I have a project with expressjs and ava, and I'm using webpack in order bundle the app

webpack is also load environment variables from .env files based 
on the NODE_ENV.

How can I load .env file variables while running ava, or alternatively bundle the app before running ava tests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to load `.env` file into your test environment. A simple example:

```
import test from 'ava';
require('dotenv').config()

test('foo', t => {
    console.log(process.env.DB_HOST);
    console.log(process.env.DB_USER);
    console.log(process.env.DB_PASS);
    t.pass();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also the combination of the two previous answers, you can specify ava to use dotenv for all tests by specifying the following in your project's `package.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "ava": {
        "require": [
             "dotenv/config"
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[This commit](https://github.com/avajs/ava/pull/2126) was merged 1st June of 2019, quite a while after the original post.

The long and short of it now, though, is that you can define environment vars for the Ava test runner inside of your project's `package.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "ava": {
        "environmentVariables": {
            "FOO": "bar",
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: How to override these variables when doing unit test?